# Using R library "od", od_to_odmatrix is generating "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, matrix, od

Trying to adapt the examples from here:
[An Introduction to origin-destination data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/od/vignettes/od.html)

Data I'm trying to work with looks like this (3 columns, 6 rows),

```
structure(list(Shed.x = c(3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8), Shed.y = c(3, 29, 
39, 74, 83, 84), Num = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Table is product of two dplyr left_joins.. But I keep getting:

> Error in out[cbind(x[[name_orig]], x[[name_dest]])] <- x[[attrib]] :
> subscript out of bounds

In response to:

```
 od_to_odmatrix(x, attrib = "Num", name_orig = "Shed.x", name_dest = "Shed.y")
```

Seems relevant:
[Creating origin-destination matrices with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263023/creating-origin-destination-matrices-with-r)[count-origin-destination-relationships-without-direct-with-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004622/count-origin-destination-relationships-without-direct-with-r?rq=1)

The igraph package generates a square/symmetical matrix (which seems to be what I want/need), but not sure how it plays with the rest of the OD library.
[Igraph library](https://www.bing.com/search?q=igraph%20package&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&lq=0&pq=igraph%20package&sc=8-14&sk=&cvid=3C52E1ACF3224A92A59AE1435E79EAC3&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=)